Bokeh gridplot with single colour bar?
Is there a proper way to add a shared colorbar (or general annotation) to a gridplot (or general layout object rather than a single figure)?
This is what I've come up with, but it feels kind of hacky as I have to fiddle with the sizes everytime I change data (number of images in the grid) and it doesn't seem to like having a plot without any renderers.
import numpy as np

from bokeh.models import LogColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, gridplot, row
output_notebook()

def normal2d(X, Y, sigx=1.0, sigy=1.0, mux=0.0, muy=0.0):
    z = (X-mux)**2 / sigx**2 + (Y-muy)**2 / sigy**2
    return np.exp(-z/2) / (2 * np.pi * sigx * sigy)

X, Y = np.mgrid[-3:3:200j, -2:2:200j]
Z = normal2d(X, Y, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0) + 0.1*normal2d(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0)
image = Z * 1e6
image2 = Z ** 2 * 1e3

color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=1, high=1e7)

plot = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), width=200, height=200, toolbar_location=None)
r = plot.image(image=[image], color_mapper=color_mapper,
               dh=1.0, dw=1.0, x=0, y=0)
plot2 = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), width=200, height=200, toolbar_location=None)
r2 = plot2.image(image=[image2], color_mapper=color_mapper,
               dh=1.0, dw=1.0, x=0, y=0)

color_bar = r.construct_color_bar(padding=1)
gridplot = gridplot([[plot], [plot2]], toolbar_location=None)

# Add color bar to an empty figure
color_bar_fig = figure(width=55, height=400, toolbar_location=None, outline_line_color=None)
color_bar_fig.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
color_bar_fig.axis.visible = False
color_bar_fig.grid.visible = False

# gridplot.add_layout(color_bar, "right")

final_layout = row(gridplot, color_bar_fig)

show(final_layout)

WARNING:bokeh.core.validation.check:W-1000 (MISSING_RENDERERS): Plot has no renderers: figure(id='p4630', ...)

